# Elipsis after two lines

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I want elipsis after two lines i have got one solution but it's not working in IE browser.

I want like this:

Amazon Childproofs Echo Speakers, 
Adds Age-Appropriate Audio Content...

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/jackyr/multi-clamp

Comment: above solution not working for me. i am unable to apply webkit box orient

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  padding: 50px;
}

.desc {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -moz-line-clamp: 2;
  -ms-line-clamp: 2;
  -o-line-clamp: 2;
  line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -ms-box-orient: vertical;
  -o-box-orient: vertical;
  box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: normal;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="desc">
  textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt
  textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt
  textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt
  textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt
  textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt textt
</div>
```